# If logged in user meta is

Tags: user-meta

I was wondering if it's possible to display certain content *if* a user meta field is set to a certain value.

The most related thing I could find is [get user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta), however it seems to get the user meta from the author of the page/post, and not from the logged in user - correct?

Appreciate any hints - cheers!

Comment: can u explain more your question?

Comment: If the answer has been helpful consider accepting it - if you need more information read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not correct - [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) returns meta data based on the `$user_id` parameter you provide. You can combine it with [`get_current_user_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id) to check if an user is logged in and than - if so - get the post meta. E.g. like this:

```
$curr_user_id = get_current_user_id();
// the value is 0 if the user isn't logged-in
if ( $curr_user_id != 0 ) {
    // we know now the user is logged-in, so we can use his/her ID to get the user meta
    $um_value = get_user_meta( $curr_user_id, 'your-key', true );
    // now we check if the value is correct
    if ( ! empty( $um_value ) && $um_value == 'your-value' ) {
        // if so we can output something
        echo 'user meta has the value';
    }
}
```